# vuejs not setting data property from arrow function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I got this weird thing going on here:

I have this data property in vue

```
    data() {
        return {
            currentLat: 'intial Lat',
            currentLong: 'intial Long',
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.getCurrentLocation();
    },
    methods: {
        getCurrentLocation() {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
                this.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
                this.currentLong = position.coords.longitude;.

                console.log(this.currentLat); this prints 41.2111

            });
            console.log(this.currentLat); this prints 'intial Lat'
        },
    },
```

[image]

> this.currentLat not set in the mount

I dont understand what's happing here! it's so weird!

Comment: You changed its value with `this.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;`

Comment: yes but when I console log  it's value it gives me the intial value not the position latitude

Comment: Because it is asynchronous, you should use it inside the callback, or convert it to a promise and use async/await

Comment: Suppose the user has blocked their geolocation, the browser will popup asking permission, the callback will only run after the user allows their geolocation

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of converting to a promise and using async/await:

```js
async getCurrentLocation() {
    const position = await new Promise(resolve => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => resolve(position))
    });

    this.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
    this.currentLong = position.coords.longitude;

    console.log(this.currentLat); // shouldn't print initial value
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is valid, the callback arrow function is asynchronous (it's not executed immediately) and the call of `console.log(this.currentLat);` is synchronous which makes it  to be executed before the callback context, the property is properly if you use it inside the template it will work fine

Comment: so what I need to do to fix this?

Comment: There's nothing to fix, your data follows the right pattern, if you want to print your data after  the update inside the callback function you could use a watcher property

Comment: Don't worry about the update of data, your properties are reactive when they change in the arrow function that change will be reflected in the UI

Answer (score 0):

Set the values in a callback as follows:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">{{ currentLat }} - {{ currentLong }}</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentLat: "intial Lat",
      currentLong: "intial Long",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getCurrentLocation();
  },
  methods: {
    getCurrentLocation() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.setCoordinates);
    },
    setCoordinates(position) {
      this.currentLat = position.coords.latitude;
      this.currentLong = position.coords.longitude;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Sane thing, call back didnt fix it

Comment: Yes, it does, what are you getting exactly? I edited the answer with a version to test.